# How do I intercept the unbuffered output of a Proc::Async in Raku?

Tags: stdout, raku, buffering

With a snippet like

```
# Contents of ./run
my $p = Proc::Async.new: @*ARGS;
react {
    whenever Promise.in: 5 { $p.kill               }
    whenever $p.stdout     { say "OUT: { .chomp }" }
    whenever $p.ready      { say "PID: $_"         }
    whenever $p.start      { say "Done"            }
}
```

executed like

```
./run raku -e 'react whenever Supply.interval: 1 { .say }'
```

I expected to see something like

```
PID: 1234
OUT: 0
OUT: 1
OUT: 2
OUT: 3
OUT: 4
Done
```

but instead I see

```
PID: 1234
OUT: 0
Done
```

I understand that this has to do with buffering: if I change that command into something like

```
# The $|++ disables buffering
./run perl -E '$|++; while(1) { state $i; say $i++; sleep 1 }'
```

I get the desired output.

I know that [TTY IO::Handle objects are unbuffered](https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-perlvar#$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH,_$%7C), and that in this case the `$*OUT` of the spawned process is not one. And I've read that [IO::Pipe](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Pipe) objects *are* buffered "so that a write without a read doesn't immediately block" (although I cannot say I entirely understand what this means).

But no matter what I've tried, I cannot get the unbuffered output stream of a Proc::Async. How do I do this?

I've tried binding an open IO::Handle using `$proc.bind-stdout` but I still get the same issue.

Note that doing something like `$proc.bind-stdout: $*OUT` does work, in the sense that the Proc::Async object no longer buffers, but it's also not a solution to my problem, because I cannot tap into the output before it goes out. It does suggest to me that if I can bind the Proc::Async to an unbuffered handle, it should do the right thing. But I haven't been able to get that to work either.

---

For clarification: as suggested with the Perl example, I know I can fix this by disabling the buffering on the command I'll be passing as input, but I'm looking for a way to do this from the side that creates the Proc::Async object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Proc::Async` itself isn't performing buffering on the received data. However, spawned processes may do their own depending on what they are outputting to, and that's what is being observed here.

Many programs make decisions about their output buffering (among other things, such as whether to emit color codes) based on whether the output handle is attached to a TTY (a terminal). The assumption is that a TTY means a human is going to be watching the output, and thus latency is preferable to throughput, so buffering is disabled (or restricted to line buffering). If, on the other hand, the output is going to a pipe or a file, then the assumption is that latency is not so important, and buffering is used to achieve a significant throughput win (a lot less system calls to write data).

When we spawn something with `Proc::Async`, the standard output of the spawned process is bound to a pipe - which is not a TTY. Thus the invoked program may use this to decide to apply output buffering.

If you're willing to have another dependency, then you can invoke the program via. something that fakes up a TTY, such as `unbuffer` (part of the `expect` package, it seems). Here's an example of a program that is suffering from buffering:

```
my $proc = Proc::Async.new: 'raku', '-e',
    'react whenever Supply.interval(1) { .say }';
react whenever $proc.stdout {
    .print
}
```

We only see a `0` and then have to wait a long time for more output. Running it via `unbuffer`:

```
my $proc = Proc::Async.new: 'unbuffer', 'raku', '-e',
    'react whenever Supply.interval(1) { .say }';
react whenever $proc.stdout {
    .print
}
```

Means that we see a number output every second.

Could Raku provide a built-in solution to this some day? Yes - by doing the "magic" that `unbuffer` itself does (I presume allocating a `pty` - kind of a fake TTY). This isn't trivial - although it is being [explored by the libuv developers](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/2640); at least so far as Rakudo on MoarVM goes, the moment there's a libuv release available offering such a feature, we'll work on exposing it.

Comment: This is very useful. I had tried using `stdbuf` but didn't get very far. For what it's worth, a Raku solution to this problem would be very welcome in my opinion.

Comment: unbuffer worked for me. On a mac: `brew install expect` to get it.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the `.out-buffer` of a handle (such as `$*OUT` or `$*ERR`) to 0:

```
$ ./run raku -e '$*OUT.out-buffer = 0; react whenever Supply.interval: 1 { .say }'

PID: 11340
OUT: 0
OUT: 1
OUT: 2
OUT: 3
OUT: 4
Done
```

Comment: Ah, yes. This is useful. But I don't have access to the command that will be specified in the arguments. Can this be done from the calling side (ie. from within the snippet)?